# React router - how to handle nested routes?

Tags: typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to add nested routes to app but to be honest I don't know how. How can I add to my app nested routes?

This is my app:

```
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import routes, { RouteModel } from './router/routes';
import CustomRoute from './router/CustomRoute';

const renderRoutes = (routes: RouteModel[]) => {
  return routes.map((route, index) => {
    if (route.SubItems && route.SubItems.length > 0) {
      return (
        <Route
          key={index}
          path={route.Path}
          element={
            <CustomRoute path={route.Path}>
              <route.Page />
              {renderRoutes(route.SubItems)}
            </CustomRoute>
          }
        />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Route
          key={index}
          path={route.Path}
          element={
            <CustomRoute path={route.Path}>
              <route.Page />
            </CustomRoute>
          }
        />
      );
    }
  });
};

const App = () => {
  return <Routes>{renderRoutes(routes)}</Routes>;
};

export default App;
```

My routes look like this:

```js
import { ComponentType } from 'react';
import CreateCarPage from '../page/car/create/page';
import HomePage from '../page/home/page';
import LoginPage from '../page/login/page';
import ListCarPage from '../page/car/list/page';

export type RouteModel = {
  Path: string;
  Page: ComponentType<any>;
  Text: string;
  SubItems?: RouteModel[];
};

const routes: RouteModel[] = [
  {
    Path: '*',
    Page: HomePage,
    Text: 'Home',
  },
  {
    Path: '/login',
    Page: LoginPage,
    Text: 'Login',
  },
  {
    Path: '/car',
    Page: ListCarPage,
    Text: 'Car',
    SubItems: [
      {
        Path: '/car/create',
        Text: 'Create',
        Page: CreateCarPage,
      },
    ],
  },
];

export default routes;
```

And my customRoute:

```
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuth } from '../context/AuthContext';
import Layout from '../component/layout/Layout';

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  path: string;
};

const CustomRoute = ({ children, path }: Props) => {
  const { authenticated } = useAuth();

  if (path === '/login') {
    return authenticated ? <Navigate to="/" /> : children;
  }

  return authenticated ? <Layout>{children}</Layout> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
};

export default CustomRoute;
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught error: a `<Route>` is only ever to be used as the child of `<Routes>` element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your `<Route>` in a `<Routes>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`renderRoutes` returns an array of `Route` components. These need to be wrapped in the `Routes` component. The root level is already handled with `<Routes>{renderRoutes(routes)}</Routes>`, the descendent routes of `route.SubItems` also need to be wrapped in `Routes`.

When a routed component renders descendent routes, e.g. more routes in a `Routes` component, the parent path necessarily needs to append a wildcard/splat `"*"` to the path so descendent route paths can also be matched and rendered.

```
const renderRoutes = (routes: RouteModel[]) => {
  return routes.map((route, index) => {
    if (route.SubItems && route.SubItems.length > 0) {
      return (
        <Route
          key={index}
          path={`${route.Path}/*`} {/* <-- append wildcard/splat */}
          element={
            <CustomRoute path={route.Path}>
              <route.Page />
              <Routes>
                {renderRoutes(route.SubItems)} {/* <-- wrapped in Routes! */}
              </Routes>
            </CustomRoute>
          }
        />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Route
          key={index}
          path={route.Path}
          element={
            <CustomRoute path={route.Path}>
              <route.Page />
            </CustomRoute>
          }
        />
      );
    }
  });
};
```

You could make the code a bit more ***DRY*** by computing if there are sub-routes to render and conditionally applying the wildcard/splat to the parent route and conditionally rendering the descendent routes.

```
const renderRoutes = (routes: RouteModel[]) => {
  return routes.map((route, index) => {
    const hasSubRoutes = !!route.SubItems?.length;

    return (
      <Route
        key={index}
        path={hasSubRoutes ? route.Path : `${route.Path}/*`}
        element={
          <CustomRoute path={route.Path}>
            <route.Page />
            {hasSubRoutes && (
              <Routes>
                {renderRoutes(route.SubItems)}
              </Routes>
            )}
          </CustomRoute>
        }
      />
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: I added to CustomRoute   console.log(path); when i click on SubItem it no push me to /car/create but it displaying /car in console

Comment: @Splitsan What are you clicking on? Is that relevant to your post/question here about rendering the descendent routes? Sounds like that may've been resolved and you've some new issue you've discovered now that the routes are rendering their content?

Comment: ok i know now what was wrong i forget to use <Outlet /> for subitems

Answer (score 0):

[image]

when i paste the link directly into the browser it redirect me to /car page not /car/create